# Why aren't my JS functions not being executed if the model of the page is populated with data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developping a web app, using ASP .NET Core 2.0

I have a partial view that contains a form.

Then I have an action method inside a controller that is executed through a JS function, that uses AJAX.
This action method populates a model and returns the form partial view and corresponding model.

The function works well, as long as the model is not populated.
I need to fetch a record from the database when a determined field is filled and then loses focus. This works for the first time, when the model used in the form is empty. However, after finding a record for the first time and filling the form, the function is not executed anymore.

Also, the validations of the field also don't work after a record is loaded.

Here's the form partial view:

```
<form id="myform">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label asp-for="Client.Name">Client</label>
            <input asp-for="Client.Name" id="ClientName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
            <label asp-for="Cliente.Phone"></label>
            <input asp-for="Cliente.Phone" id="Phone"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

The JS/AJAX function:

```
<script>
$("form").on("blur", "#Phone", function () {
    var phone = document.querySelector('#Phone').value;
    alert('select client by phone=' + phone);

    //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/GetClienteByPhone",
        data: "phone=" + phone,
        success: function (res) {
            $('#myform').html(res);
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Finally, the controller action method (Controller=Home):

```
public IActionResult GetClienteByPhone(string phone)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone))
        {
            var model = new FormViewModel();

            model.Client = _db.Clients.Where(c => c.Phone == phone).FirstOrDefault();

            return PartialView("_Form", model);
        }
        return PartialView("_Form");
    }
```

On my View, I render the partial view into a div with id="myform"

Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Paulo,  code example would be great just to understand how you're calling the scripts from the views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the post with some code examples.

Comment: Could you Add [HttpPost] Attribute to your Action Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're replacing your entire form in the AJAX callback. When you do that, you're also killing any attached event handlers. If you need the event handler to persist, you need to delegate it to a parent element that remains on the page after the replacement. You are using jQuery's delegate handler function, but your delegate itself is being replaced. You either need to not replace the entire form and just replace some child inside, or use a higher parent element than your `form`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Chris Pratt !
That was exactly it!!